# Find the second smallest and second largest values of a set of number in Java

Tags: java, max, min

Find the second smallest and second largest values of a set of numbers. The solution must be such that these values are found in a single pass of the input. The input set may be empty or could be quite large: the size is not known a priori.

Can you guys help me with flowchart and pseudo code? Thanks in advances

My current flowchart looks like this:

[image]

Comment: sorry we only help if you have tried something.If yes then post your code clearly mentioning what problem you are facing

Comment: Does your teacher know you are here?

Comment: @JqueryLearner My thought is i will sort the set of numbers from smallest to largest, and then the value that stand after the smallest value will be the second smallest value, same with second largest, the value that stand before the largest value will be the second largest value. if there is any duplicate then will keep going until get the new value.BTW, I dont have to do any code, just get idea to draw flowchart and write pseudo code.

Comment: @Benj Well try your way,I am busy in my work otherwise I would have done.If you face problem then ask

Comment: @JqueryLearner I am confusing that the idea i said above okay or should i try by using 4 variables and then compares? thanks for your help

Comment: We can help you by checking your flowchart and/or pseudo code, if you tell us what it isn't doing correctly and what you've tried so far to fix it. If you want help creating them, this isn't the place. General hints: If you can solve it for the smallest and largest, you can solve it for the second smallest and second largest... and you don't need a sort.

Comment: Do note that one of the properties of the set is that it never holds any duplicate values.

Comment: I got my flowchart done by using raptor. However, when test the data.txt file, it display all number in the file. So can anyone know what am i doing wrong? Thanks . Link to the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UiFEv.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are missing the point; if you need to do it 'in a single pass' then calling a sorting algorithm first will mean more than one pass through the data. Ditto for putting the data into a sorted set, etc.

This is not a complete answer, but a broad hint..

To solve this, think about how you would solve a simpler problem: consider how you would find the largest value 'in one pass' -- you start with the first value in the list, and then walk through the list one at a time - every time you saw a larger value than your current value, you would discard the previous largest value and save the new largest. While you are walking through your list, you could also compare against the smallest value, and replace your current smallest value with the new, smaller value. When you got to the end of the list, you would have found both the largest and the smallest in a single pass.

Now think about how you could extend this logic to find the second-largest item: what do you test for each time you look at a new number? is it bigger than your largest number? is it bigger than your second largest? etc.

Update: you will have to do some special-case logic for a list with less than two items in it: the question doesn't really make sense for a list with length < 2, so it's up to you to decide what to do with those inputs. (i.e. what would your teacher like to see?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it in a single pass, having the inputs in a sorted order will be easy. If its in a sorted order, you can just find the size and then use the position [1] and [n-1] to find your numbers.

Note: index starts from 0

Also, if you are using map or some format which will not allow duplicate values, then you can directly get the values. No need for duplicate check. In this way, you can solve it in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SortingNo {
static int[] removeDuplicates(int arr[]) {    
  java.util.HashSet<Integer> set = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    final int len = arr.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }
    int[] whitelist = new int[set.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (java.util.Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        whitelist[i++] = it.next();
    }
    return whitelist;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int arr[]={2,2,45,5,78,8,78,23};        
    arr=removeDuplicates(arr);        
    java.util.Arrays.sort(arr);//Sorts the specified array of objects into ascending order        
    System.out.println("Smallest:"+arr[0]);        
    System.out.println("2nd Smallest:"+arr[1]);
    System.out.println("Largest:"+arr[arr.length-1]);
    System.out.println("2nd Largest:"+arr[arr.length-2]);
}
}
```

Comment: (I know, I made this comment on another answer, but I think it applies here, too) I think, by calling Arrays.sort(), you are not meeting the requirement of doing this 'in one pass' (in one pass, to me, implies it would have to be O(N) operation - any sorting algorithm [other than maybe a radix-based sort] would be at least O(n log n), and examine each item more than once.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[] getSecondMinAndMax(int[] in) {
    if (in == null)
        return new int[0];

    Arrays.sort(in);

    if (in.length > 3) {
        return new int[]{in[1], in[in.length-2]};
    } else if (in.length == 3) {
        return new int[]{in[1], in[1]};
    } else {
        return new int[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, by calling Arrays.sort(), you are not meeting the requirement of doing this 'in one pass' (in one pass, to me, implies it would have to be O(N) operation - any sorting algorithm [other than maybe a radix-based sort] would be at least O(n log n), and examine each item more than once.